# Encoding "<" and ">" while sending XML via HTTP Post

Tags: http, ms-access, post, xmlhttprequest

I am sending an XML content via HTTP Post from Access VBA to Web Methods, using XMLHTTP object in MSXML. Here is the Code.

```
Dim objXmlHttp As Object
Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXmlHttp.Open "POST", webServicePath, False
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Dim Response As String
objXmlHttp.send wrt.output

'OK status
If objXmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
    Response = objXmlHttp.responseText
End If
Set objXmlHttp = Nothing
```

I am getting the XML with "&lt" and "&gt" instead of < and >. 
If I try to do URL encoding, everything is received as ASCII text in the Recipient side. 
Can you please guide what I need to do to get the valid XML format.

Comment: I don't see you URL encoding the output.

Comment: VBA does not have a URL encoding mechanism. I am just using a Common Code. 

Function URLEncode(strData)
  Dim I, strTemp, strChar, strOut, intAsc
  
    strTemp = Trim(strData)
    For I = 1 To Len(strTemp)
        strChar = MID(strTemp, I, 1)
        intAsc = Asc(strChar)
        If (intAsc >= 48 And intAsc <= 57) Or (intAsc >= 97 And intAsc <= 122) Or (intAsc >= 65 And intAsc <= 90) Then
            strOut = strOut & strChar
        Else
            strOut = strOut & "%" & Hex(intAsc)
        End If
    Next
URLEncode = strOut
End Function

Will this solve my issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the content-type correctly, try this instead:

```
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""utf-8"""
```

Comment: When I include this content type, I am not getting the XML content in the Reveiving end.

Comment: Worth noting: @AndrewHare's suggested Content-Type preserves the text as-entered for sending, but places it in the Data field instead of the Form field.