# Msxml2.XMLHTTP does unwanted URL encoding translation?

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest, twilio, twilio-twiml, scada

I'm using CitectSCADA's CitectVBA environment to make a POST request to Twilio's Twimlets server, via an `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` object.  After discovering some of the differences between this and Office's VBA v6, I did manage to get the thing to make a POST request.

```
Dim TwiMLURL As String
TwiMLURL = "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%3CSay%3EThis%20Is%20a%20test.%20Say%20Alarm%20Trip%20" _
& almNum &".%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&"

Dim http As Object
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")

http.Open "POST", GetCallURL(), False, ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Dim postData As Variant
postData = "From=" & TwilioNumber _
    & "&To=" & toNumber _
    & "&Url=" & TwiMLURL

' send the POST data
Print postData
http.send postData
```

The issue I'm having now is that the input I'm giving for the `Url` parameter of the request has valid URL encoding for XML characters, but the response I get indicates that these codes went through as their corresponding HTML Ampersand Character Codes.

My output for the code above:

```
The thread 1 has started.
From=+15555556430&To=+15555551597&Url=http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%3CSay%3EThis%20Is%20a%20test.%20Say%20Alarm%20Trip%20111.%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>21205</Code><Message>Url is not a valid url: http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=&lt;Response&gt;&lt;Say&gt;This Is a test. Say Alarm Trip 111.&lt;/Say&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21205</MoreInfo><Status>400</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>
The thread 1 has terminated.
```

Any ideas as to where the translation is happening? I'm so close to being able to make Citect call an operator's phone and read the code of the currently active alarm!

**UPDATE:** I just ran my POST request through [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) and confirmed that Twilio received it correctly - the call went through to my phone and read the Twimlet-encoded message as requested.  So the problem is with `Msxml2.XMLHTTP`.  Any thoughts on how I might get around this?

**UPDATE 2:** [Encoding “<” and “>” while sending XML via HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406487/5403341) solved the initial POST error: I've updated my request header.

```
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""utf-8"""
```

Now, however, I'm getting a response saying that no "To" number is specified:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>21201</Code><Message>No 'To' number is specified</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21201</MoreInfo><Status>400</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>
```

My phone numbers are formatted as `%2B15555556430`. Is there another encoding problem here? I don't even know how to investigate what Msxml2.XMLHTTP is sending this time.

**UPDATE 3:** The problem is with MSXML2.XMLHTTP.  When I send my post data to [httpbin.org/post](http://httpbin.org/post) to have it echo back what I've sent, it returns the following objects, depending on which `Content-Type` header I choose:

With `text/xml; charset=""utf-8""`:

```
"args": {}, 
"data": "From=%2B15555556430&To=%2B15555551597&Url=http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%20%20%3CSay%3EM%20G%20141%20E%20Q%20P%20S%20A%20Alarm%20Trip%20111%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&", 
"files": {}, 
"form": {},
```

With `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
"args": {}, 
"data": "", 
"files": {}, 
"form": {
    "From": "+15555556430", 
    "To": "+15555551597", 
    "Url": "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=<Response>\n  <Say>M G 141 E Q P S A Alarm Trip 111</Say>\n</Response>"
},
```

With `application/json`:

```
"args": {}, 
"data": "From=%2B15555556430&To=%2B15555551597&Url=http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=%3CResponse%3E%0A%20%20%3CSay%3EM%20G%20141%20E%20Q%20P%20S%20A%20Alarm%20Trip%20111%3C%2FSay%3E%0A%3C%2FResponse%3E&", 
"files": {}, 
"form": {},
```

I actually tried swapping in `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` in place of `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` and got exactly the same results.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you see in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger) what POST request body is being received by Twilio?

Comment: @philnash While that's helpful in that I didn't know it existed, my debugger logs are empty. I get the impression that this debugger logs attempts at using the Runtime Functions, which I had not set up.

Comment: Can you send your request to a http://requestb.in/ to see what is being sent? Might give you some more insight.

Comment: Just had this idea yesterday on the way home. I used [httpbin.com/post](http://httpbin.org/post). I've isolated the problem to Msxml2.XMLHTTP's 'send' method, which does different things with different Content-Type headers.  I'll update the question with my findings.

Comment: I recommend setting the content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is what Twilio is expecting to receive. What happens if you do that?

Comment: @philnash See the update to my question. `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` and `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` both translate the URL-encoded characters to un-encoded characters.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are posting to `TwiMLURL` which looks encoded.  You are posting to the return value of `GetCallURL()`.

```
http.Open "POST", GetCallURL(), False, ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN
```

Comment: This is true, but that's not where the problem was.  The URL produced by that function is correct. I just discovered part of the answer under [Encoding “<” and “>” while sending XML via HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406487/5403341).  Now, however, I'm getting a different error message.  I've updated the initial post to reflect this.